# How to test if a javascript object is a Date using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a Javascript array of strings and want to extract the ones that are dates following this format `DD/MM/YYYY`.

With moment you can check this doing:

`moment("31/12/2015", "DD/MM/YYYY").isValid(); -> true`

However, these are also considered valid dates, when they shouldn't:

```
moment("1", "DD/MM/YYYY").isValid(); -> true
moment("1/", "DD/MM/YYYY").isValid(); -> true
moment("1/1", "DD/MM/YYYY").isValid(); -> true
```

Any idea how I could enforce a strict string validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use strict mode in your parsing. Strict mode will cause Moment to only match inputs that exactly match the format string. Just pass true as your third parameter:

```
moment("1", "DD/MM/YYYY", true).isValid();
false
moment("1/", "DD/MM/YYYY", true).isValid();
false
moment("1/1", "DD/MM/YYYY", true).isValid();
false
```

Note that in strict mode, using the DD and MM tokens, Moment will start expecting two digit days and months. Thus:

```
moment("1/1/2016", "DD/MM/YYYY", true).isValid();
false
moment("01/01/2016", "DD/MM/YYYY", true).isValid();
true
```

You may want to go to the one letter tokens. Then either one will work:

```
moment("01/01/2016", "D/M/YYYY", true).isValid();
true
moment("1/1/2016", "D/M/YYYY", true).isValid();
true
```

There's more information about the how and why of strict mode in the parsing guide: http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/